# In the tour, only answer being accepted later (second one) has a checkmark

Tags: bug, status-completed, tour

[image]

Which is definitely a bug (on any SE site). It is a bit misleading to a new user.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying with your image. I see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/A5jey.png) after the animation has occurred, up voting the second answer and accepting it.

Comment: @Andy From the tour, it looks like the first answer is impossible to accept because it lacks the checkmark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this issue out. I've changed the tour so that the accepted answer checkbox appears for both possible answers. It will be live in the next StackExchange.com production release (> rev `2014.9.22.1135`).

Comment: Either it wasn't really fixed or it has been broken again

Comment: @nicael please open a new meta post and we'll investigate!

Comment: I don't get the reason why I should open a new post...

Comment: @nicael this one is resolved and has an accepted answer. You can link this post in a new one.

Comment: Ok I am going to post a new bug report.

Comment: Posted: [In the tour, the checkmark is gone from the second answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251562/in-the-tour-the-checkmark-is-gone-from-thr-second-answer.)