# In the tour, the checkmark is gone from the second answer

Tags: bug, tour

<sub>*[Exactly the same as this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239718/in-the-tour-only-answer-being-accepted-later-second-one-has-a-checkmark), but I was told to post a new report by a developer.*</sub>

The bug is on the answer ([tour page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour)), which isn't going to be accepted, doesn't have a check mark.

> [image]